# Errors in MySQL Stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a little problem and I didn't resolve it!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE selection_socioprof(IN age INT,IN prof varchar(50))
BEGIN

declare calcul number;
declare prc_cat number;
declare nb_particip number;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nb_particip FROM questionnaire;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO calcul 
FROM questionnaire
where question2=age AND question3=prof;
prc_cat:=(calcul/nb_particip)*100;
concat('le pourcentage des participants aux jeux SMS ayant la
 catégorie        socioprofessionnelle choisie est',prc_cat);

END;
```

**And this is the error:**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'number' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE selection_socioprof(IN age INT,IN prof VARCHAR(50))
 BEGIN
    DECLARE calcul INT; 
    DECLARE prc_cat INT; 
    DECLARE nb_particip INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nb_particip FROM questionnaire;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO calcul FROM questionnaire  WHERE question2=age AND question3=prof;
    SET prc_cat := (calcul/nb_particip)*100;
    SELECT CONCAT('le pourcentage des participants aux jeux SMS ayant la catégorie socioprofessionnelle choisie est',prc_cat);

  END; //
  DELIMITER //
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE selection_socioprof(IN age INT,IN prof varchar(50))
 BEGIN
 declare calcul int(10);
 declare prc_cat int(10);
 declare nb_particip int(10);
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nb_particip FROM questionnaire;
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO calcul FROM questionnaire where question2=age AND question3=prof;
 set prc_cat=(calcul/nb_particip)*100; 
select concat('le pourcentage des participants aux jeux SMS ayant la catégorie socioprofessionnelle choisie est',prc_cat); END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: i try this solution but the error isn't solved yet!! this is the new error:

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
declare prc_cat int(10),
declare nb_particip int(10),
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n' at line 4

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE selection_socioprof(IN age INT,IN prof varchar(50))
BEGIN
declare calcul int(10),
declare prc_cat int(10),
declare nb_particip int(10),
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nb_particip FROM questionnaire;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO calcul 
FROM questionnaire
where question2=age AND question3=prof;
prc_cat:=(calcul/nb_particip)*100;
concat('le pourcentage des participants aux jeux SMS ayant la catégorie socioprofessionnelle choisie est',prc_cat);
END;

Comment: use delimiters, check proper SP syntax